# daily to monthly sum in matlab of multiple years

Tags: matlab, loops

My data is excel column. In excel sheet one column contain last 50 years date (no missing date; dd/mm/yyyy format) and in other column everyday rainfall (last 50 years; no blank).

I want to calculate what is the sum of monthly rainfall for every month of last 50 years in Matlab. Remember, there four types of month ending date: 30, 31, 28 and 29. Upto now I am able read the dates and rainfall value from excel file like below

```
filename = 'rainfalldate.xlsx';

% Extracts the data from each column of textData

[~,DateString ]= xlsread(filename,'A:A')

formatIn = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

DateVector = datevec(DateString,formatIn)

rainfall = xlsread(filename,'C:C');
```

what is the next step so that I can see every months of last fifty years rainfall sum?

I mean suppose July/1986 rainfall sum... Any new solutions?Code or loop base in Matlab 2014a

Comment: but you already converted it into a date vector, all you have to do now is to index the correct year and month (you can do this using find) and then sum it up...

Comment: Take a look at `accumarray`

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel suggested, you could use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for this.

Since you want the monthly rainfall for multiple years, you could combine year and month into one single variable, `ym`.

It is possible then to identify if a value belongs to both a determined year *and* month at once, and "tag" it using [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) function. Values with similar "tags" are summed by the `accumarray` function.

As a bonus, you do not have to worry about the number of days in a month. Take a look at this example:

```
% Variables initialization
y=[2014 2014 2015 2015 2015 2014 2014 2015 2015];
m=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3]; % jan, feb and march
values = 1:9;

% Identifyier creation and index generation
ym = y*100+m;
[~,subs]=histc(ym,unique(ym));

% Sum
total = accumarray(subs',values);
```

The `total` variable is the monthly rainfall already sorted by year and month (yyyymm).

Comment: No problem. Just let me know if the answer worked for you by accepting it. If you have any doubts just ask